# Displaying the latest data in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone please help me? I'm a newbie on PHP so please understand.
Here's my code.

```
$query="SELECT MAX(mid) as mid, ticketno FROM tbl_message GROUP BY ticketno";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo $row['mid'];
echo $row['ticketno'];
}
```

DISPLAYS THIS

```
 - mid    ticketno
 - 2-------21510
 - 1-------24693
 - 4-------24693
```

WHAT I WANT

```
 - mid    ticketno
 - 2-------21510
 - 4-------24693
```

My database :

[image]

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Does your query, with GROUP BY, really return ticketno 24693 twice?!?

Comment: @Jay thank you for informing me. I will on my next project. I dont want to re code again

Comment: are you storing the ticketno as varchar or as an integer?

Comment: as varchar. my 'mid' is auto incremental

Comment: Why varchar for ticketno?

Comment: will it help me get what i want if its a integer ?

Comment: how does the program know you don't want `1-------24693`?  what is that logic?

Comment: OMG It worked !!! @jarlh. im sorry i didnt know !! why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so basically I just changed varchar to int (type of TICKETNO)
then it returns the most latest ticketno.

I used this query

```
$query="SELECT MAX(mid) as mid, ticketno FROM tbl_message GROUP BY ticketno";
```

i used MAX() to return only the latest ticket no and GROUP BY ticketno so that it would return the other unique ticket no.

I guess varchar reads spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ORDER BY` . Try with -

```
$query="SELECT mid, ticketno FROM tbl_message GROUP BY ticketno ORDER BY mid DESC";
```

Comment: i dont know why i doesnt work on me. it returns 3-24693||2-21510||1-24693

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_message t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                   FROM tbl_message t2
                   WHERE t2.ticketno = t.ticketno
                   AND t2.mid > t.mid
                  )
```